# How Do I Access Stringified JSON In A Step Function Task's Input Path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

The [new StartExecutionCommand()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sfn/interfaces/startexecutioncommandinput.html) command requires the `input` to be a string.

For example in my Lambda that is invoked by AWS API Gateway:

```
  const stepFunctionParams: { stateMachineArn: string; input: string; name: string; } = {
    stateMachineArn: process.env.STEP_FUNCTION_ARN!,
    input: JSON.stringify(event.body),
    name: `NetSuiteInventorySet${Date.now()}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}` 
  };

await client.send(new StartExecutionCommand(stepFunctionParams));
```

This then sends the JSON as a string to the Step Function.

How do I access the specific key value pairs in the stringified JSON provided by the Lambda? Whilst it requires a string, can I just send `event.body`?

Attempts and Errors:

1. `inputPath: JsonPath.stringToJson("$.product.sku"),` - Error = `Type 'IResolvable' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Your command is a SDK command.  Your errors look like CDK errors.  More code context would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've found there are two solutions:

1. For input, just pass the value of `event.body`. Whilst we say we want a `string`, this works and did not offer new errors
2. Use a Lambda at the start of the step function that parses stringified JSON.